# If $G$ is nilpotent and $H$ a subgroup of index $p$ (prime) in G, is then $H \lhd G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it possible maybe that such a subgroup has to be maximal? Because then it would follow that $H$ is normal in $G$?

I know that a maximal subgroup of a finite nilpotent group is normal, but I don't remember if it is the other way around also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any subgroup of prime index in any group is maximal. You seem confused. "I know that a maximal subgroup of a finite nilpotent group is maximal" does not make much sense.

Comment: @DerekHolt I meant to write "a maximal subgroup of a finite nilpotent group is normal".

Comment: My bad, I read too fast

Comment: Astyx, $\langle 4 \rangle$ had index $4$. So what is the point?

Comment: Prime index implies that the subgroup is maximal, by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti You're right. I don't know why I wasn't seeing this before.